# Foundation Grid issue

Tags: performance, grid, zurb-foundation, multiple-columns, fluid-layout

I'm trying 2 make from a large-12 column, one large-8 column and the other large-4 column.

In the 8-large column, making 4 more columns, like large-3 columns, or small-3 columns.

When i'm testing it, in Chrome, all good good, but in IE, FF, O, all that large-3 or small-3 columns are floating out of the container.

HTML markup :

```
<div class="row">
                   <div class="large-8 small-3 columns">CONTENT</div>
                   <div class="large-8 small-3 columns">CONTENT</div>
                   <div class="large-8 small-3 columns">CONTENT</div>
                   <div class="large-8 small-3 columns">CONTENT</div>

                   <div class="large-4 columns">CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

I tried with the following html markup:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="large-8 columns">
     <p class="text">bla bla bla</p>
     <div class="row">
        <div class=large-3 columns>CONTENT</div>
        <div class=large-3 columns>CONTENT</div>
        <div class=large-3 columns>CONTENT</div>
        <div class=large-3 columns>CONTENT</div>
     </div>
   </div>
  <div class="large-4 columns">CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

Is the markup correct ?

I little preview :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I just had to add `width: 100%;` at all images.

Thank you